# how kotlin use stdlib.jar?

Tags: kotlin, import

I'm new in Kotlin, nowadays there is a problem disturbed me for a long time. I find we didn't import any packages or classes when we use functions such as let which defined in kotlin-stdlib.jar. I'm curious about how it works in such way.

Answer (score 3):

It works the same was as it works in Java for the `java.lang` package: some Kolin packages are automatically imported.

See [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#default-imports)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is another problem for me. I wanna know if you have any suggestion for me. I want to change the package name in kotlin source and build the kotlin-stlib.jar by myself. How can I do that?

Comment: No, really, you don't want to do that. That's like first asking what wings are for on a plane, and immediately after, ask how you can build an Airbus A320 by yourself.

Comment: But now I truly have a problem that I can only find such a method to solve it. I have to build leakcanary module which written in Kotlin to a jar, because most apps which call the jar are written in Java,so have to build leakcanary jar with kotlin-stdlib.jar. But the problem is that those apps written in Kotlin depends on different version of kotlin-stdlib.jar, so there is a confliction. And we can't change those apps' kotlin-stdlib.jar's version. I try to change the package name of kotlin-stdlib.jar, but I find it can't work, because apps call kotlin-stdlib.jar don't use import.